# Converting time_t to a DATE struct in c

Tags: c, time-t

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct Date {
   short day, month, year;
} DATE;
```

I want to create a function that gets a `time_t` variable and convert it to `DATE` but I am having some issues with it.
Tried the following:

```
DATE timeTConverter(time_t date) 
{
    struct tm *giverTime;
    giverTime = localtime(date);
    DATE given;
    given.day = giverTime->tm_mday;
    given.month = giverTime->tm_mon++;
    given.year = giverTime->tm_year;

    return given;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 5):

[`localtime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) takes **a pointer to** `time_t`, not `time_t` itself.

Also incrementing `giverTime->tm_mon` doesn't make sense because the result is not used. It seems you wanted to assign `giverTime->tm_mon + 1` instead.

```
DATE timeTConverter(time_t date) 
{
    struct tm *giverTime;
    giverTime = localtime(&date); /* pass a pointer */
    DATE given;
    given.day = giverTime->tm_mday;
    given.month = giverTime->tm_mon+1; /* simply add instead of increment */
    given.year = giverTime->tm_year;

    return given;
}
```

Comment: Probably also need to add 1900 to the `tm_year` value.